# KFold Cross Validation

Tags: cross-validation

KFold cross validation technique trained a new model using K-1 training batches and predict on left out batch and finally drop all such trained models.
I have few follow up questions:

1. What is the utility of KFold cross validation, if it's getting
   trained again(from the start) on K-1 batches?
2. Since it's not using my own pre-trained model for evaluation, does it mean it's not useful for the model that I fit(and wants to
   evaluate)?

Answer (score 0):

To clear the air, let me remind that we typically do CV for model selection / hyperparameter (HP) optimization. KFold is a type of CV, where we train $K$ models and test on the holdout/validation sets. Each of these $K$ models use nearly $(K-1)/K$ of the training data and test on the the remaining (i.e. $1/K$ of training data). With good enough validation success metric, we decide on the best model and train *a single model* with all the training data we have, not with the $(K-1)/K$ of training set.

You could use your pre-trained model (e.g. with the best performing HP set) on the test set, but you miss the opportunity of including one of your holdout sets in the training if you do so, i.e. you just throw away your validation set because you train on the $(K-1)/K$ of your training set, and evaluate your model on the test set. You can also evaluate on the validation set, but since you tuned your model by looking at the holdout, it won't be an objective result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can we say that KFold(or any cross validation) is used to find out the best model out of many models that we have trained?

Comment: @vipinbansal, in a nutshell, yes.